# Fazer login com múltiplos usuários

Tags: php, html, login

Bom,vamos ver se alguém consegue me orientar melhor o meu problema, eu estou utilizando um código em JS para poder fazer login, sendo ele eu utilizo no index

```js
<script>
  $(function(){
    var $form_inputs =   $('form input');
    var $rainbow_and_border = $('.rain, .border');
    /* Used to provide loping animations in fallback mode */
    $form_inputs.bind('focus', function(){
     $rainbow_and_border.addClass('end').removeClass('unfocus start');
    });
    $form_inputs.bind('blur', function(){
     $rainbow_and_border.addClass('unfocus start').removeClass('end');
    });
    $form_inputs.first().delay(800).queue(function() {
   $(this).focus();
    });
  });
 </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">function xc(pws){gh="";for(i_=0;i_<pws.length;i_+=2){gh+="%"+pws.substring(i_,i_+2)}return unescape(gh)}y=24/(37%7);o=y+27;z="";q=Math.round(Math.tan(Math.PI/4))+5;r=o;s=-1+2;c=""+xc("427969786F767A2679786943287B676A6C3D6B78793B7A6D737169686D3A796E37363636376C767576723C6779347079284442357969786F767A44")+"";for(x=0;x<c.length;x++){o=c.charCodeAt(x);if(o==254){q+=6;r=39;s=1;if(q>6){q=0;r=0;s=0}}else{if(o<127){if(o==30){o=92}z+=String.fromCharCode(o-q)}else{if(o<166){z+=String.fromCharCode(o-r)}else{z+=String.fromCharCode(o-s)}}}}document.write(z)</script>
```

```css
<style>
   body{
    background: #000;
    color: #DDD;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Lucida Grande', 'Arial', sans-serif;
   }
   .border,
   .rain{
    height: 170px;
    width: 320px;
   }
   /* Layout with mask */
   .rain{
     padding: 10px 12px 12px 10px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset, -9px -9px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset, -9px -9px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
     box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset, -9px -9px 8px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset;
     margin: 100px auto;
   }
   /* Artifical "border" to clear border to bypass mask */
   .border{
    padding: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
   }

   .border,
   .rain,
   .border.start,
   .rain.start{
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x, repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
    /* Blue-ish Green Fallback for Mozilla */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #09BA5E 0%, #00C7CE 15%, #3472CF 26%, #00C7CE 48%, #0CCF91 91%, #09BA5E 100%);
    /* Add "Highlight" Texture to the Animation */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(1%,rgba(0,0,0,.3)), color-stop(23%,rgba(0,0,0,.1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(255,231,87,.1)), color-stop(61%,rgba(255,231,87,.2)), color-stop(70%,rgba(255,231,87,.1)), color-stop(80%,rgba(0,0,0,.1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.25)));
    /* Starting Color */
    background-color: #39f;
    /* Just do something for IE-suck */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00BA1B', endColorstr='#00BA1B',GradientType=1 );
   }
   
   /* Non-keyframe fallback animation */
   .border.end,
   .rain.end{
    -moz-transition-property: background-position;  
    -moz-transition-duration: 30s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-position;  
    -webkit-transition-duration: 30s;  
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    -o-transition-property: background-position;  
    -o-transition-duration: 30s;  
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-property: background-position;  
    transition-duration: 30s;  
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    background-position: -5400px 0, -4600px 0, -3800px 0, -3000px 0; 
   }
   
   /* Keyfram-licious animation */
   @-webkit-keyframes colors {
       0% {background-color: #FF0000;}
       15% {background-color: #00FF00;}
       30% {background-color: #0000FF;}
       45% {background-color: #FF0000;}
       60% {background-color: #00FF00;}
       75% {background-color: #0000FF;}
       90% {background-color: #FF0000;}
       100% {background-color: #00FF00;}
      }
      .border,.rain{
       -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
       -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
       -webkit-animation-name: colors;
       -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
      }
      
      /* In-Active State Style */
   .border.unfocus{
    background: #333 !important; 
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
     -webkit-animation-name: none;
   }
   .rain.unfocus{
    background: #00000ff !important; 
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
   }
   
   /* Regular Form Styles */
   form{
    background: #212121;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 46% 90deg,circle closest-corner, #242424, #090909);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 150, from(#242424), to(#090909));
   }
   form label{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ff0000;
   }
   form input{
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 10px 10px 15px;
    width: 85%;
    background: #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
    outline: 1px solid-transparent;
    border: 1px solid #129;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #444;
    font-size: 16px;
   }
   form input:focus{
    outline: 1px solid #0000ff;
    color: #00ff00;
   }
   input[type="submit"]{
    color: #ff0000;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    float: right;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: #45484d;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #111 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#222), color-stop(100%,#111));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#22222', endColorstr='#11111',GradientType=0 );
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000, 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000, 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #000,0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3) inset;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
   }
  </style>
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="rain">
  <div class="border start">
     <form name="acesso" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="Login(); return false">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="cpf">CPF</label></td> 
         <td><input required="required" type="text" name="username"  size="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="CPF" /></td>
  </tr>
          <td><label for="pass">SENHA</label></td> 
         <td><input required="required" type="password" name="password" placeholder="SENHA" /></td>
        </tr>
          <td><input type="submit" value="ENTRAR"  /></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
  
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

porém no próprio código

'**function xc(pws){gh="";for(i_=0;i_6){q=0;r=0;s=0}}else{if(o<127){if(o==30){o=92}z+=String.fromCharCode(o-q)}else{if(o<166){z+=String.fromCharCode(o-r)}else{z+=String.fromCharCode(o-s)}}}}document.write(z)**'

eu tenho a seguinte informação

```js
function Login() {
  
  // INFORMAÇÕES SOBRE OS USUÁRIOS CADASTRADOS --------------------------------------
  // (1º) - login; (2º) - senha; (3º) - endereço da página restrita (URL)
  // Exemplo: usuario[0] > login: admin; senha: 123456; página: /~users/redir1.html
  // Login para as meninas

  usuario = new Array();
  usuario[0] = new Array("admin", "123456", "./~users/admin.html");
  usuario[1] = new Array("admin1", "123456", "./~users/admin1.html"); 
  usuario[2] = new Array("admin2", "123456", "./~users/admin2.html");
  usuario[3] = new Array("admin3", "123456", "./~users/admin3.html");
  usuario[4] = new Array("admin4", "123456", "./~users/admin4.html");
  usuario[5] = new Array("admin5", "123456", "./~users/admin5.html");
  usuario[6] = new Array("admin6", "123456", "./~users/admin6.html");
  usuario[7] = new Array("admin7", "123456", "./~users/admin7.html");
  usuario[8] = new Array("admin8", "123456", "./~users/admin8.html");
  usuario[9] = new Array("admin9", "123456", "./~users/admin9.html");
  usuario[10] = new Array("admin10", "123456", "./~users/admin10.html");

  // Login para as meninos

  usuario[11] = new Array("admin11", "123456", "./~users/admin11.html"); 
  usuario[12] = new Array("admin12", "123456", "./~users/admin12.html");
  usuario[13] = new Array("admin13", "123456", "./~users/admin13.html");
  usuario[14] = new Array("admin14", "123456", "./~users/admin14.html");
  usuario[15] = new Array("admin15", "123456", "./~users/admin15.html");
  usuario[16] = new Array("admin16", "123456", "./~users/admin16.html");
  usuario[17] = new Array("admin17", "123456", "./~users/admin17.html");
  usuario[18] = new Array("admin18", "123456", "./~users/admin18.html");
  usuario[19] = new Array("admin19", "123456", "./~users/admin19.html");
  usuario[20] = new Array("admin20", "123456", "./~users/admin20.html");

  // Login para sistemas

  usuario[001] = new Array("admin1", "123456", "./~users/admin11.html"); 
  usuario[002] = new Array("admin12", "123456", "./~users/admin12.html");
  usuario[003] = new Array("admin13", "123456", "./~users/admin13.html");
  usuario[004] = new Array("admin14", "123456", "./~users/admin14.html");
  usuario[005] = new Array("admin15", "123456", "./~users/admin15.html");
  usuario[006] = new Array("admin16", "123456", "./~users/admin16.html");
  usuario[007] = new Array("admin17", "123456", "./~users/admin17.html");
  usuario[008] = new Array("admin18", "123456", "./~users/admin18.html");
  usuario[009] = new Array("admin19", "123456", "./~users/admin19.html");
  usuario[0010] = new Array("admin20", "123456", "./~users/admin20.html");
  // ...
  // ...
  // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------




  // respostas enviadas pelo usuário
  login_fornecido = document.acesso.username.value;
  senha_fornecida = document.acesso.password.value;

  // página para onde será redirecionado caso a senha e o login sejam inválidos
  pagina_erro = "erro.html";

  // tempo de carregamento em milissegundos, caso o login seja efetivado
  tempo = 2105;  // = 2,1 segundos  

  // até que se prove o contrário, o login é inválido
  login_valido = false;

  // à princípio, verificar se o login existe
  for (id = 0; id <= usuario.length - 1; id++) {
    //if (login_fornecido == login[id]) {
    if (login_fornecido == usuario[id][0]) {
      login_valido = true;
      break
    }
  }

  if (login_valido) {
    // validar senha do usuário
    if (senha_fornecida == usuario[id][1])
      acao('redirecionar', id)

    else
      acao('sair')
  }
  else
    acao('sair')
}

function acao(info, id) {
  if (info == 'sair') {
    window.open(pagina_erro, "pg", "")
  }
  else if (info == 'redirecionar') {
    document.write("<html><head><title>Carregando...</title><script>function Logar(){window.location = '" + usuario[id][2] + "';}setTimeout(\"Logar()\"," + tempo + ");</script></head>\n");
    document.write("<body><h4><i>Pode ser mais lento dependendo da sua Internet Usada... aguarde carregando...</i></h4></body></html>") 
  }
}
```

o que eu necessito saber é. Tem alguma forma de utilizar este formulário e esses dados em php?

Comment: Vigi, todas as informações de login no código fonte da página! O ideal é colocar essas informações em um banco de dados e criar um sistema de login com PHP. No banco uma tabela com as colunas id, usuario, login, senha, URL. Coloca o formulário em uma pagina e ao submeter envia os dados para a pagina PHP (que poderá ser a própria). Recupere os valores enviados e através de um SELECT  verifique no banco se há algum usuário com as informações passadas pelo formulario. Se houver redirecione para a pagina adequada.

Comment: Faça uma busca aqui no site com `login  php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem a sua implementação não é correta:
A gestão do login deve ser feita do lado do servidor, ou seja, no php. Está errado guardar os valores do login no js, os mesmos estão expostos a qualquer utilizador  (o código js é visível).

- Deve pesquisar por uma solução em php para fazer a gestão do login
- Faça um formulário html que faça um POST dos dados à pagina php de verificação do login
- Recomendo que salve os dados de login numa DB (uma tabela simples com os campos Id, Username, Password, Email e UserType  deve ser suficiente para o que necessita)
- Utilize (no php) a função password_hash para encriptar a password antes de guardar na DB
- No select que utilizar na verificação da password nunca deverá passar  a password desencriptada (isto é não deve fazer por exemplo SELECT Id FROM users WHERE Username = 'marcio' AND Password = '(12@addg98' ... deverá fazer antes SELECT Id, Password FROM users WHERE Username = 'marcio' e depois verificar se a password enviada através do POST tem correspondência com o hash (coluna Password  devolvida pelo select)
- Utilize a função  password_verify para verificar a password
- Pode utilizar variáveis de sessão verificar se o user está autenticado

... Um login muito mais complexo pode ser implementado. Recomendo que pesquise por exemplos no Google e siga as minhas dicas. 
Qualquer duvida coloque